# Getting WM_TOUCH messages from every window and processing in my APP

Tags: c#, winapi, visual-studio-2010, windows-7

I am developing touchscreen application. The goal of the application is when the end user is going to make vertical touch movement (a vertical line with his finger)on the screen on touchscreen device with Windows7 all of the active windows need to minimize (something like show desktop). My question is how can i process all the WM_TOUCH messages that happen everywhere in every window that is active on the desktop. There is no windows hook with which i can take all the WM_TOUCH messages. I tried to use the WH_GETMESSAGE with hope that i can extract the WM_TOUCH messages but is not working, I tried to use the WH_MOUSE_LL and got all the mouse events. There is function GetMessageExtraInfo with which i can see from where the mouse messages is initiated with this code:

if ((GetMessageExtraInfo().ToInt32() & MOUSEEVENTF_FROMTOUCH) == 0xFF515700)
            {
               textBoxLog.AppendText("asdada");
            }
if this is true then the message is initiated by TouchScreen device. This works only with the messages that are sent from my app(my app active window), but not with the mouse messages i am getting from the other windows outside my app window. I am researching this subject for a while and i still can't get any answer. So please if someone knows any way how can i get all the WM_TOUCH messages to my app please respond.

Mihail

Answer (score 1):

You must hook the global message proc. This way you are the first to get at all the messages. The way you are doing this will not work because your wndproc is only "active" when your windows is active.

Simply create a new wndproc that processes only the messages you want to be global and either allowing them to pass through or cutting them off depending on the logic you want.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644990%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: I am using code from this project http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/globalhook.aspx version2 it is working for the mouse and keyboards hook, when i try to register for WH_GETMESSAGE it is not working my app is not triggered in the events. The other thing i try is  when i get the mouse events that i get from the mouse hook i use the GetMessageExtraInfo() on the message to check is it from touch device the messages for the messages for my app is ok but when i touch the screen outside it gets the mouse message but it shows that is now made from touch device.Any example code how can i buildyour ans

Comment: I am not sure since I haven't used that code before and since it is in C# you will have to do some extra stuff(which I suppose that globalhook code does). All I can say is make sure your WM_ codes are correct. If it is working for the mouse and keyboard then it should work for touch if there are no issues with compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

According to a [similiar discussion on Windows DevCenter](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/a92ae6ff-67d3-4e3f-90b6-137004c4b230/how-to-hook-the-wmtouch-message) this doesn't seem to be possible:

> There is no good way to catch touch input globally on Windows 7. As Bob mentioned, windows need to be specifically registered to receive touch input and this isn't something that can be safely done for other applications' windows.