# How to catch WM_TOUCH with global hook?

Tags: c#, c++, winapi, hook

Using global hook to detect WM_TOUCH event, I have no idea.
I saw the following link, registering handle to window as local hook.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317326(v=vs.85).aspx

But, it's not the way. It is for local hook.
I want to filter event, recognizing whether to detect WM_TOUCH or not.

---

I connected the touch monitor as USB type. Even though I touch the monitor, all events are such as WM_MOVE or WM_LBUTTONDOWN. I can not see any WM_TOUCH. 
I assume it is required to register something to get WM_TOUCH.

Comment: I cannot understand the question. Can you please give us a little more context and background. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4701539/getting-wm-touch-messages-from-every-window-and-processing-in-my-app

Comment: I connected the touch monitor as USB type. Even though I touch the monitor, all events are such as WM_MOVE or WM_LBUTTONDOWN. I can not see any WM_TOUCH. 
I assume it is required to register something to get WM_TOUCH.

Comment: You will not receive `WM_TOUCH` messages for a window, unless you called [RegisterTouchWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317326.aspx) previously.